# Casting (int)enum to a object property does not get passed when called by razor view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, enums

Using MVC 5 and Razor pages.

The scenario is when I cast (int)colour to a Item property called Colour which is of type INT in my HttpGet method. This value *should be passed* to the ViewModel, and i store it as a hiddenfield on razor view.

So when debugging my code:

return View(viewModel); the viewModel.Colour = 23 - which is **correct**.

This will now display the Razor view, and inside this razor view i store the model.House value into a hidden field, so i can perform a HttpPost.

At this stage my raw URL is:
applicationName/**Orange**/Item/Create?date=2014-08-05&**_1236723545**

Notice there is Orange in the Colour param in the url, and also a model which is at the end, which has a Colour property, which has the number 23.

Now once iv completed filling the form in, and press save, the ModelState is not valid at this stage, because for some odd reason in the razor view 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Colour)
stores the string value "Orange" instead of 23, which has been provided by the model. Now i understand the names clash in the URL and my object model, but surely this should work.

My Route Config

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Item",
    url: "{colour}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Item", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

My Get method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(Colour colour, DateTime? date)
{
    var viewModel = new Item()
    {
        ItemDate = (!date.HasValue ? DateTime.Now.Date : date.Value),
        Colour = (int) colour,
        ItemTypeId = 1
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

My Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Item item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _itemService.Create(item);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Item", new { date = item.itemDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") });
    }
    return View(item);
}
```

SO my question is how do i get my razor view to ignore the colour that is written in url and to use colour which is the Item property. So instead of "Orange" it should be 23.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: forms use a combination of posted data and URL values. Having a duplicate name is not a great idea. Can you rename your route param, e.g. to `col`, as that name is not important (so long as you match it in routing/links)?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thank you yes i changed the route param name as this was causing the issue, however because the project is fairly big so the change was required else where in links, so i found an alternative solution, as i believe the Binding was causing the issue, so in my Post method i added [Bind(Exclude = "Colour")], and this has overcome the issue, without making amends to the other parts of the project. Not sure if this is the right approach but will continue to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly excluding it is a good way to go:

```
public ActionResult YourMethod([Bind(Exclude = "Colour")] Item item{

    //Implementation

}
```

Another option is to explicitly INCLUDE all of the parameters from the request that you want to bind to:

```
public  ActionResult YourMethod([Bind(Include = "NotColour1, NotColour2")] Item item{

    //Implementation

}
```

I tend to prefer this method because

1. Visual Studio stubs it out this way when it scaffolds stuff (not a technically sufficient reason, but good enough)
2. Gives me a bit more confidence security-wise, because you say what IS and not what CANT be and I therefore feel just a little bit more in control.

I agree with the suggestion, though, that you should look into choosing different names for non-related things (or at least put them in separate namespaces?)